# An Array of N-th elements , trying to add elements from left to right and right to left

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array where the number of elements is chosen by user. after user chose number of elements , introduce the value of each element. after that the program should calculate if the sum of 2 or 3 elements in order to find a corespondent value it can be found in array. for ex, I have the fallowing values:
3,6,4,9 ---> 3+6=9 and 4 is the number that is != with this sum. for this type of example i found a way to calculate the sum.
if I change ex : 9,4,6,3 ---> 3+6=9. in this way i have no ideea how to sum elements from right to left coz 3 is the N-th element of the array.

The code is written in C

If someone have any ideea or advice it will be great. Thx !

Comment: Don't describe your code. Show it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: pus=&a[0];
        e=*pus;                                                                                                   for(b=0; b < y;b++){
        d = e + *(pus+1);
        if(d==*(pus+b))
            printf....else
               r=d + *(pus+2);
                if(r==*(pus+b))
                    printf....

Comment: it's sum elements from left to right.

Comment: @Bob for clarifications please edit your question instead of posting comments. And please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, and assuming you are writing in C, an easy approach (but with the cost of O(n^3) which is very much) would be to calculate for each element, the sum of it with each other element, and then compare with each element...Confusing?

The code would be something like the following for the above approach:

```
for (int i=0; i<ArrayLength; i++){
     for (int j=0; j<ArrayLength; j++){
         int tempVar = Array[i] + Array[j]; // Calculate every element with every other element
         for (int k=0; k<ArrayLength; k++){ // Check if that calculation meets equality with another Array Element.
                 if (k==i || k==j) continue;
                 if (tempVar == Array[k]) 
                     printf("You have a match for the sum of %d and %d elements with the element in position %d\n",Array[i],Array[j],Array[k]);
         }
     }
}
```

Note that the code above is nothing close to something that is useful to implement due to its cost and i am only providing it for algorithmic ideas purposes.

Please provide with some piece of your code if you need more help than some algorithm idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
  printf("\nArray size: ",y);
  scanf("%d",&y);
  printf("\nValues: ",n);
  w=0;

      for(b=0 ; b < y ; b++)
   {
       scanf("%d",&a[b]);
      printf("\nElements are [%d]: %d \n",b,a[b]);
}

    pus=&a[0];
    e=*pus;

for(b=0; b < y;b++)
{
    d = e + *(pus+1);
    if(d==*(pus+b))
        printf("\nIt found element [%d]: %d\n",b,d);
        else
           r=d + *(pus+2);
            if(r==*(pus+b))
                printf("\nIt found element [%d]: %d\n",b,r);
}
```